# Request JSON Web-Server

Tags: android, json, web-services

I'm doing an android app, where I'm trying to implement a JSON request for a web server. I'm using the library: android-async-http-1.4.6.jar.
I wrote the following code:

```
public void RequestToServer() {

    try {

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        // params.put("uid", User_id.toString());
        JSONObject cred = new JSONObject();

        cred.put("user",LoginActivity.m_user);
        cred.put("pwd", LoginActivity.m_pwd);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        cred.put("anno", Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)));

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(cred.toString());

        client.post(this, "http://vdctest.agrishare.com/list_up", entity, "application/json",responseHandler);

    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

But I'm mistaken about voice responseeHandler in client.post and I'm not able to figure out what the problem is? Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What does or doesn't happen? Also, empty catch blocks are not a good idea since you are just silently catching an error that might tell you the problem

Comment: "mistaken about voice responseeHandler".. what does that mean? is your responsehandler called at all?  Did you recognize the url you are calling is returning 404?

Comment: I can not fill in the code because I'm mistaken about responseHandler. I do not understand if some class is missing or not.

Comment: Sorry, again not sure: you cannot compile and run your code, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

from the comments and typical google examples i assume you just missed to implement the responsehandler method for some reason.

I recommend to go on by adding an inline function for responsehandling as in the accepted answer here:

[android-async-http post request with body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644560/android-async-http-post-request-with-body)